# Websocket Spring: Can't connect from external client

Tags: javascript, spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I am trying to connect to my websocket destination from an external client. I have the following on my external client:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    connect('test');

    function connect(selectedUser) {
        var socket = new SockJS("http://<my-ip>:<my-port>/Messages/getMessages");
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

            stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
              console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
              stompClient.subscribe('/topic/newMessages/' + 'test', function (response) {
                alert("New Message!")

              });

          });
    }

});
```

I get the following:

> Opening Web Socket... 
>   Whoops! Lost connection to
>
> > http://my-ip:my-port/Messages/getMessages

But if I run this code from the internal client it runs fine.
Now, the external client is on IE6, but based on the SockJS documentation, this should not be a problem.

Comment: isnt that same origin policy issue? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-allowed-origins

Comment: Ok, I think that worked, but now I get the following issue:
"this.ws=new a(this.url,[],o)" : Object doesn't support this action
The line above is in my sockjs.js file, and my sockjs version is 1.1.1. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I fixed the above issue by using sockjs 0.3 instead. But now I'm not receiving any messages when I publish them to the destination my client is subscribed to....